# rewiring a basement light

Tags: lighting, switch

I have a light switch in my basement that controls  three lights how do I make each light come on with its own  switch so do I I go from a three way switch to a two way switch on the main switch and add to more two way switches  for the other two lights

Comment: Can you provide more detail about where the switches are, what wires are in each switch box and where you want the final switches?

Comment: Are you asking how to connect each wire and each splice??? "Cause that what it seems you are asking.

Comment: Currently at the bottom of our stairs we have a 3 way switch Which controls 3 lights in out basement we are putting 2 bedrooms in the basement and want each light to have an independant switch

Comment: You will certainly have to be doing some re-wiring to achieve this goal. If you are adding bedrooms I believe you will want to have the switches for the lights in each room be just inside the door to that room.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, there is no code that the room light switch be "just inside the door", that is a myth code. The code is simply that there is a switch somewhere in the room that controls something, be it a receptacle or fixture.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - I said NOTHING about electrical code. As a matter of conventional usage and convenience I suggested what I did. Your comment is out of place here.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, Oh well, sorry you got offended. My comment stands. Your comment "I believe you will want to..." implies that it is required. Sure, what you wrote is conventional, but code is what I am concerned with.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, OK buddy. Whatever you say. Again, sorry you got butt hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Rob, thank you for explaining what you are doing, but I got that from your original question. What you need to do is re-wire the complete lighting arrangement in your basement.

My suggestion is to remove what's there and put in exactly what you need in each room/area. If you do not know what to do this wiring please simply hire an electrician to do this job for you.

If you are making this into bedrooms there are several other VERY important codes you MUST follow, such as AFCI protection for any circuits in the rooms, smoke/CO detectors, means of egress, etc.